# Trouble with the proof of Cauchy convergence criterion

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing, proof-explanation, cauchy-sequences

While reading the Analysis 1 textbook by Vladimir A. Zorich I encountered a proof which has this one conclusion I fail to understand.

The theorem and proof :

**(Cauchy’s convergence criterion) A numerical sequence converges if and only if it is a Cauchy sequence.**

*Proof.*

$\implies$:(I skipped this part of the proof since I have no issues with it.)

$\impliedby$:
Let ${x_k}$ be a fundamental sequence. Given $\epsilon > 0$, we find an index $N$ such that $|x_m − x_k| < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$ when $m ≥ N$ and $k ≥ N$. Fixing $m = N$, we find that for any $k >N$
$$x_N − \frac{\epsilon}{3}<x_k <x_N + \frac{\epsilon}{3}\ \text{,} \ \ \ \ \ \text{(3.1)}$$
but since only a finite number of terms of the sequence have indices not larger than $N$, we have shown that a fundamental sequence is bounded.

$$\text{For}\ n \in \mathbb{N}\ \text{we now set } a_n := \inf_{k≥n} x_k ,\ \text{and }\ b_n := \sup_{k≥n} x_k \ \text{.}$$

It is clear from these definitions that $a_n ≤ a_{n+1} ≤ b_{n+1} ≤ b_n$ (since the greatest lower bound does not decrease and the least upper bound does not increase when we pass to a smaller set). By the nested interval principle, there is a point A common to all of the closed intervals $[a_n, b_n]$. Since
$$a_n ≤ A ≤ b_n$$
for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and
$$a_n = \inf_{k≥n} x_k ≤ x_k ≤ \sup_{k≥n} x_k = b_n$$
for $k ≥ n$, it follows that
$$|A − x_k| ≤ b_n − a_n\ \text{.}\ \ \ \ \ \text{(3.2)}$$
But it follows from Eq. $\text{(3.1)}$ that
$$\underbrace{x_N − \frac{\epsilon}{3}≤ \inf_{k≥n} x_k = a_n ≤ b_n = \sup_{k≥n} x_k ≤ x_N + \frac{\epsilon}{3}}_{\text{The problematic part}}$$
for $n>N$, and therefore
$$b_n − a_n ≤ \frac{2\epsilon}{3} < \epsilon \ \ \ \ \ \text{(3.3)}$$
for $n>m$. Comparing Eqs. $\text{(3.2)}$ and $\text{(3.3)}$, we find that $|A −x_k| < \epsilon$, for any $k > N$, and we have proved that $\lim_{k \to \infty}x_k = A$.

*End of proof.*

---

The underbraced part doesn't make sense to me, because from the stated it could happen that $$x_N − \frac{\epsilon}{3} = a_n $$ and since $a_n≤x_k$ it is possible that $a_n=x_k$ and if those equalities hold, then $x_N − \frac{\epsilon}{3} = a_n=x_k$, but this contradicts what was stated before in $\text{(3.1)}$, $x_N − \frac{\epsilon}{3}<x_k $.

Why does the problematic part hold despite this ?
Thanks

Comment: I think you just proved that both equalities can't simultaneously hold at once.

Comment: @Berci What do you mean by simultaneously? And where in the proof is stated that it's not simultaneously ? Or I didn't understand what you said..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the two possibilities

i) $x_N-\epsilon/3 =a_n$

ii) $\,a_n = x_{k_0}$ for some $k_0\ge n.$

Each of these cases can arise, but not simultaneously. For if i) holds, then $a_n$ can't equal $x_{k_0},$ simply because $x_{k_0} >x_N-\epsilon/3.$ Thus if i) holds, ii) cannot hold. And if ii) holds, then $a_n=x_{k_0}> x_N-\epsilon/3,$ which implies i) can't hold

So the "problematic part" is not really problematic.

Comment: Many thanks sir, btw. the quote in your profile by Abel is very cool. Have a nice day

Comment: Thanks, glad I could help. Also, glad you liked Abel.

Answer (score 2):

If $x_N − \frac{\epsilon}{3}<x_k <x_N + \frac{\epsilon}{3}$ holds for all $k>N$, then $ x_N-\frac{\epsilon}{3}≤ \inf_{k≥N} x_k$ and $ \sup_{k≥N} x_k ≤ x_N + \frac{\epsilon}{3}.$ Combine these two, to get the underbraced inequality and then the rest of the proof go through. Note, you hve used the generic $n$, which is not quite right. The inequalities follow one after the other, for $k>N$, which you fixed previously.

Maybe a more detailed proof will help with the ideas:

$(1).$ Since $(x_n)$ is Cauchy, it is bounded. And it's much easier to see this simply by taking $\epsilon=1$ and finding an integer $N$ such that $n,m>N\Rightarrow |x_n-x_m|<1$. Then, $|x_n|<\max\{|x_1|,\cdots |x_N|,|x_{N+1}|+1\}.$

$(2).$ Since $(x_n)$ is bounded, it has a convergent subsequence (I will give a proof of this at the end). So,

$(3).$ Let $x_{n_k}\to x$. Then, there is an integer $K$ such that if $k>K,\ |x-x_{n_k}|<\epsilon/2$. And there is an integer $N$ such that if  $n>N, |x_m-x_n|<\epsilon/2.$ Now, choose an integer $l>K$ such that $n_l>N$. Then, if $n>N, |x_n-x|\le |x-x_{n_l}|+|x_n-x_{n_l}|<\epsilon.$

Proof of $(2):$ Let $(x_n)$ be a bounded sequence. Then there exists some $M > 0$ such that $|x_n| \le M$ for all integers $n$. Bisect the interval $[−M, M]$ into two closed intervals of equal length. One of these intervals must contain infinitely many $x_n.$ Let $I_1$ be that interval, and choose $x_{n_1}\in I_1$. Now, bisect $I_1$ into two closed intervals. Let $I_2$ be the subinterval of $I_1$ that contans infinitely many $x_n$, and choose one, $x_{n_2}\neq x_{n_1}$ such that $n_2>n_1$ (why is this possible?). In general, having constructed $\{I_j:I_j\subset I_{j-1},\ 1\le j\le k-1\}$, bisect $I_{k−1}$ into two closed intervals, one of which must contain infinitely many terms of $(x_n).$ Let $I_k$ be this closed interval, and choose $x_{n_k}\in I_k$ such that $n_k > n_{k−1}.$ Therefore, the induction proceeds and we obtain a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ and  a sequence of nested intervals $\{I_k\}_k$ whose diameters $|I_k|=M\cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k-1}$ tend to $0$ as $k\to \infty.$ This fact, and the Nested Interval Property, imply that the intersection $\bigcap I_k$ contains exactly one point $x$. Now let $\epsilon>0$ and choose $K$ such that $M\cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{K-1}<\epsilon.$  Then, if $k>K,\ x_{n_k}\in I_k$ and $|I_k|<\epsilon.$ But, $x$ is contained in $\textit{every}\ I_k$ so $|x_{n_k}-x|<\epsilon.$ It follows that $x_{n_k}\to x.$

Comment: Could you please explain more what is wrong with my reasoning at the end? I used a wrong n? Btw thanks for the additional proofs, they are very neat. I have encountered those or very similar ones while readin Abbot’s ‘Understanding Analysis’, great book..

Comment: I think equation 3.1 is wrong. You have $x_k<x_N$ for any $k>N$. This need not be so for the sequence to be bounded. For example, $x_k=(-1)^k$ is bounded but there is no $N$ for which $x_k<x_N$ for all $k>N$. Instead of trying to follow this proof, why not write it out yourself?

Comment: So you are telling me it is a mistake in the textbook ? Since 3.1 is stated in the original proof. Well I am not sure about the given sequence $x_k=(-1)^k$ since it isn't satisfying the conditions of a Cauchy sequence, which is our beginning assumption, that we have a Cauchy sequence and we go on from there. Well, I am new to this and I am still learning the patterns and 'rules' of proving stuff, hopefully I will start proving myself soon

Comment: Sorry typo I meant $\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$. I am not saying the book is wrong. Just that it does not make sense to me. Anyway, the proof I provided is standard and takes care of the matter, right?

Comment: But then it is nowhere stated that $x_k<x_N$ for all $k>N$ as you said in the comment above(Maybe I am missing something here?). Yeah, your proof seems very reasonable to me. I would still like to figure this one out, just for the sake of it. Many thanks for your effort

Comment: $x_N − \frac{\epsilon}{3}<x_k <x_N + \frac{\epsilon}{3}\ \text{,} \ \ \ \ \ \text{(3.1)}$

Comment: You want to say that that 3.1 inequality and $x_k < x_N$ are the same ? Sorry, but I honestly don’t see how that is the case here

Comment: it says Fixing $m=N$, we find that for any $k>N$.....then comes 3.1

Comment: Yeah I was aware, but I am still not getting your point. Hey man don’t bother, you helped me already enough

Comment: One last comment: when I do these kind of proofs, I draw a lot of pitcures.  They basically tell you how to proceed...good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to extract out the real issue (which is bothering you) from all the other irrelevant details given in the proof.

Let $M=x_N-(\epsilon /3)$ and then we are given that $$x_k>M\tag{1}$$ for all $k\geq N$. This clearly implies that $$a_N=\inf _{k\geq N}x_n\geq M\tag{2}$$ and since $a_n$ is increasing (another equivalent term is non-decreasing) we have $$a_n\geq a_N\geq M\tag{3}$$ whenever $n\geq N$.

It is quite possible that for some value $n_0\geq N$ we have $a_{n_0}=M$ in which case from $(3)$ we have $$M=a_N=a_{N+1}=a_{N+2}=\dots=a_{n_0}$$ Now your argument is that $$a_{n_0}=\inf_{k\geq n_0}x_k$$ and hence there could be some value $x_k=a_{n_0}=M$ and this would contradict $x_k>M$.

Well this can't be the case because the values of $x_k$ are given beforehand to satisfy $x_k>M$. Their infimum $a_n$ may equal $M$ but when this happens the infimum will not be equal to any $x_k$ it will rather be less than all $x_k$.

A typical example is $x_k=1/k$ and $\inf x_k=0$ but you clearly see that the infimum is not equal to any value of sequence.

---

To sum up, the bounds of the sequence are given apriori and they can't be invalidated at a later stage. If the sequence values are always greater than some lower bound and infimum equals that lower bound it necessarily and trivially means that the sequence values are greater than the infimum.

Answer (score 0):

You just reversed cause and result: as we have for $x_N − \frac{\epsilon}{3}<x_k <x_N + \frac{\epsilon}{3}$ for $k>N$ (3.1), then from $x_N − \frac{\epsilon}{3}≤ \inf_{k≥n} x_k = a_n$ it is impossible to have $x_N − \frac{\epsilon}{3} = a_n=x_k$.